# Google Page Speed Insights Complaining About Caching of Google Tag Manager (3rd Party)?

Tags: javascript, caching

Google page insights tool is complaining about caching tracking code that is inserted by google tag manager.

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

Some Examples:

- https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js (15 minutes)
- https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js (20 minutes)
- ttps://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WF52R9R (15 minutes)

I have added the proper cache-control headers from my web server, but because the resources are being served from 3rd party i have little control.

Is there a way to force a cache control policy on these 3rd party resources when linked from my server?

Is my only other option to save the resources locally, and have some sort of build task that will check for any updates or changes to the code and overwrite the local copy?

Comment: IMO you can safely ignore these. They're essentially spurious false-positives, and these sorts of resources tend to have short expiry dates for a reason.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to force a cache control policy on these 3rd party resources when linked from my server?

No. Their HTTP headers are their own business.

> Is my only other option to save the resources locally, and have some sort of build task that will check for any updates or changes to the code and overwrite the local copy?

No… because you don't have that option in the first place.

Those kind of scripts depend on the user's browser accessing them directly (and setting cookies associated with Doubleclick's/Facebook's/Google's domains).

---

Heuristic checkers like Google Page Insights identify *potential* issues, not absolute ones. Their warnings need to be taken with a grain of salt and a lot of understanding. Definitely don't treat issues they raise as "must fix".